# "SCRIPT1028: Expected identifier, string or number" in ie7 and ie8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

I have a problem with my map script. It works properly in every browser except Internet Explorer 7 and 8. I did the research and after reading few threads I checked my code for any trailing commas or reserved names, but either it is not the problem, or I'm just blind and really can't see where the actual problem is. The faulty code is located in the bottom part of snippet below (supposedly).

```
var arrAddress = new Array();

        arrAddress[0] = jQuery('.address-holder0').text();
        arrAddress[1] = jQuery('.address-holder1').text();
        arrAddress[2] = jQuery('.address-holder2').text();

        var optionMap = {
            MapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            disableDefaultUI: true,
            styles: [
                {stylers: [{hue: '#C80071'}, {lightness: -60}, {saturation: 100}]}
            ]
        };

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googleMap'), optionMap);

        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

        var latlngbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

        asyncLoop(arrAddress.length, function(loop){
            geocoder.geocode({
                'address': arrAddress[loop.iteration()]
            }, function(results, status) {
                if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    var image = '<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/map_pin.png';
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        map: map,
                        position: results[0].geometry.location,
                        icon: image
                    });

                    latlngbounds.extend(results[0].geometry.location);

                }

                loop.next();
            });
        }, function() {
            map.fitBounds(latlngbounds);
        });

        function asyncLoop(iterations, func, callback) {
            var index = 0;
            var done = false;
            var loop = {
                next: function(){
                    if (done) {
                        return;
                    };

                    if (index < iterations) {
                        index++;
                        func(loop);

                    } else {
                        done = true;
                        callback();
                    };
                },
                iteration: function(){
                    return index - 1;
                }, 
                break: function(){ // the error is located here 
                                   //(at least that's what ie says)
                    done = true;
                    callback();
                }
            };
            loop.next();
            return loop;
        };
```

Trying to do anything with the comma before just prevents the script from running (plus I actually believe that it is needed there).

I'd appreciate any help.
Thanks,
E.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I checked my code for any trailing commas or reserved names

You didn't look very hard. `break` is a reserved word in JavaScript and although ES5 updated the spec to allow the use of reserved words as property identifiers, IE8 and below do not implement that spec.

Change the name of the property or wrap it in quotes.